# gfortran mixes up types of real

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I want to compile a large code and it throws this error:

```
/Users/redies/fleur/types/types_lapw.F90:178:47:

     CALL boxdim(cell%bmat,arltv1,arltv2,arltv3)
                                               1
Error: Type mismatch in argument 'bmat' at (1); passed REAL(4) to REAL(8)
/Users/redies/fleur/types/types_lapw.F90:69:47:

     CALL boxdim(cell%bmat,arltv1,arltv2,arltv3)
                                               1
Error: Type mismatch in argument 'bmat' at (1); passed REAL(4) to REAL(8)
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/fleur_MPI.dir/types/types_lapw.F90.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/fleur_MPI.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

in the function boxdim the first variable is given as

```
  REAL,    INTENT (IN)  :: bmat(3,3)
```

The boxdim function is given in an *.f-file. The type cell is given as (in *.f90-file):

```
  TYPE t_cell
     !name of 2D-lattice type
     CHARACTER*3::latnam
     !vol of dtilde box
     REAL::omtil
     !2D area
     REAL::area
     !bravais matrix
     REAL::amat(3,3)
     !rez. bravais matrx
     REAL::bmat(3,3)
     !square of bbmat
     REAL::bbmat(3,3)
     !d-value
     REAL::z1
     !volume of cell
     REAL::vol
     !volume of interstitial
     REAL::volint
     REAL:: c
  END TYPE t_cell
```

everything is compiled with the -fdefault-real-8 option. If I set bmat in t_cell to

```
REAL(8) :: bmat
```

it compiles fine. Why does gfortran ignore the -fdefault-real-8 for some files? This error does not appear if I work on a fresh clone from the git repo, it starts to appear after I work on this repo for a while.

I am totally baffeled by this bug. My gfortran version is GNU Fortran (Homebrew GCC 8.2.0) 8.2.0 on MacOS, but I have the same error on 7.2.0 on Ubuntu.

P.S. the whole code compiles just fine in ifort

Comment: One of the gfortran developers recommends that user should never use the -fdefault-* options available with gfortran.  He claims that the options may not do what a naive user thinks.  He recommends that one should properly declare his/her variables.  If you are sure that you want to use -fdefault-real-8 option, then you probably want the -freal-4-real-8 option instead.

Comment: I just tried ```-freal-4-real-8``` and it doesn't help the situation. Rewriting the whole code might be a little much work.

Comment: Well you are lucky in gfortran that it signals the problem (saves a lot of debugging). in ifort you should have a look at the options `-gen_interfaces -warn interfaces` and you might find something more. Regarding " Rewriting the whole code might be a little much work." so you prefer buggy code ?

Comment: Why a I lucky? It's valid code. I use ```real``` everywhere, but somehow gfortran sometimes interprets it as ```real(8)``` sometimes as ```real(4)``` and then complains that it doesn't match.

Comment: @stein "it doesn't help the situation" isn't too descriptive.  I'm afraid we will need to see the entire piece of code to provide any help.  The -freal-4-real-8 option is a sledgehammer with promotion from `real(4)` to `real(8)`.  BTW, if you have multiple files that you are compiling, then all files must be compiled with these options.

Comment: Lucy in the sense that a mismatch in arguments leads to unpredictable results and is very hard to debug.

Comment: My guess is that you have a different error somewhere else. Are you *sure* there's nothing else going on? What if you try to strip the code down to a simple working example? If not, I don't think we can really help beyond "don't do it this way".

Comment: I can't reproduce this bug in a minimal example. It just doesn't appear there. It doesn't appear in ifort either. I know it's tricky for you to understand what my mistake is, but I though maybe someone has encountered this before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the first comment, why not resolve your problem altogether by simply declaring the kinds of reals you need according to portable modern Fortran rules:

```
module t_cell_mod

    use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only: RK => real64
    implicit none

    type t_cell

        !name of 2D-lattice type
        CHARACTER(len=3) :: latnam

        !vol of dtilde box
        real(RK) :: omtil

        !2D area
        real(RK) :: area

        !bravais matrix
        real(RK) :: amat(3,3)

        !rez. bravais matrx
        real(RK) :: bmat(3,3)

        !square of bbmat
        real(RK) :: bbmat(3,3)

        !d-value
        real(RK) :: z1

        !volume of cell
        real(RK) :: vol

        !volume of interstitial
        real(RK) :: volint
        real(RK) :: c

    end type t_cell

end module t_cell_mod
```

if you need any other real kind, simply point `RK` to other kinds (`real32`, `real128`), instead of playing with compiler options. `REAL(8) :: bmat` is not portable.